# Connect from EC2 Instance to VPC Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Currently I have an EC2 Instance with both Apache / MySQL server running. What I want to do is to sepparate them, leaving one machine for each server. I thought about connecting my currently public EC2 instance (Apache only) to a VPC instance with a MySQL server only accesible from my EC2 private IP address. But I can't seem to be able to connect.

Is this possible? Or my Apache-running machine must be an VPC instance too?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put both EC2 instances inside the same VPC and only assign an Elastic IP to the one running Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your help David, i'll try putting both machines inside VPC.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *directly* possible, because the private address space used by EC2-Classic instances is completely unrelated to -- and isolated from -- the private address space used within any given VPC.

The only way to accomplish this is by exposing the VPC instance running MySQL to the Internet so that your "external" (from the VPC perspective) EC2 instance can connect to it, with an elastic IP or by some other mechanism like proxying through another VPC-based instance that is Internet-accessible... this would amount to a potential security issue, and more things to go wrong with your assessment.

Splitting your web server and database is highly advisable, since neither Apache and MySQL are designed with hard caps on resource consumption, and they [don't always play well together](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem) on the same server, when resources (like memory) get tight.

But I would suggest that even though it's *indirectly* possible by way of some proxying and port translating gyrations, moving both machines inside VPC would be the way to go.